# How to make action animations timing right?

Tags: cocos2d-x

short story is i have sprites i want to move down i use CCMoveTo action in a loop
the problem is that i can't or didn't found away to "wait" until the previews animation is   finished .to start the next one.
the main problem is i dont know how many sprites will be , so i can't use CCSequence with fixed number of action.

```
int GemsToRemoveHolderCount = GemsToRemoveHolder->count();

    for(int i=0;i<GemsToRemoveHolderCount;i++)
    {

            Gem* gemNew = (Gem*)GemsToRemoveHolder->objectAtIndex(i);
            CCPoint posNew = gemNew->getGemPos();
            CCMoveTo *moveGemDownAction = CCMoveTo::create(0.3f,posNew);
            gemNew->runAction(moveGemDownAction);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CCDelayTime](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V2.1.4/d6/dde/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_delay_time.html) action - what it does is it simply introduces delay before or between actions, depending on where you put it in a sequence.
This is of course only viable if you are able to calculate the time needed to wait.

Another solution may be to subclass and write your own action, which may be more time consuming, but will give you more control on what is actually happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CCCallFunc action in sequence with your move action to create animation ended callback. There you can check if you need to run animation again. Run every time sequence of only one CCMoveTo action and CCCallFunc action.

Comment: so what's the problem? run this sequence, in callback check if it is need to run another CCMoveTo, create next sequence, run it with the same callback, check if it is need to run another CCMoveTo.... and so on. every sequence will contain single CCMoveTo and CCCallFunc as callback

Comment: recursion of the callbacks?

Comment: Something like this. First time call it somewhere outside callback method and then repeat it while there is need to run another animation for this node.